# Android Open Accessory SDK error INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY 

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Android Open Accessory SDK error INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294152/android-open-accessory-sdk-error-install-failed-missing-shared-library)

Using the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) and Google API 10.

Run in the emulator, I can install it, however when I run on my Android 2.3.4 device, Eclipse gave this error.

How can this be solved?

> DemoKitLaunch] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>
> DemoKitLaunch] Please check logcat output for more details.
>
> DemoKitLaunch] Launch canceled!