# Android Open Accessory SDK error INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android

Using the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) and Google API 10.

Run in the emulator, I can install it, however when I run on my Android 2.3.4 device, Eclipse gave this error.

How can this be solved?

> DemoKitLaunch] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>
> DemoKitLaunch] Please check logcat output for more details.
>
> DemoKitLaunch] Launch canceled!

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/ezterry/manifest-gingerbread-DS/issues/32#issuecomment-1564927

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run an application on a device or emulator that lacks some shared library. The most likely cause of this is that you are trying to use the Google Maps SDK Add-On and you are trying to run your application on a device or emulator that does not have the Google APIs.